# Remove everything except characters between '<' & '>,' in Vim -- extract email addresses from Gmail "To" field

Tags: vim, text-extraction, email-address

I have a comma-delimited list of email addresses with each actual address prepended by the contact's name (from Gmail).  Here's an example:

```
Fred Flintstone <fred@flintstone.org>, Wilma Flintstone <wilma@flintstone.org>, Barney Rubble <barney@rubble.org>, Bamm-Bamm Rubble <bammbamm@rubble.org>,
```

converts to:

```
fred@flintstone.org, wilma@flintstone.org, barney@rubble.org, bammbamm@rubble.org,
```

Background info:  I am trying to paste the list of contacts into a webex invite, which can only accept email addresses.

[Remove everything except regex match in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503748/remove-everything-except-regex-match-in-vim) is related, but all the email addresses are on one line in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
:s/.\{-}\%(\(,\s*\)\|<\(.\{-}\)>\)/\1\2/g
```

The following will also work:

```
:s/.*/\=join(map(split(submatch(0), ','), "matchstr(v:val, '<\\zs.*\\ze>')"), ', ')
```

Comment: `:s/.*/\=join(map(split(submatch(0), ','), "matchstr(v:val, '<\\zs.*\\ze>')"), ', ')` works, too.

Answer (score 2):

with awk

```
    echo "Fred Flintstone <fred@flintstone.org>, Wilma Flintstone <wilma@flintstone.org>, Barney Rubble <barney@rubble.org>, Bamm-Bamm Rubble <bammbamm@rubble.org>
"|awk -F'<|>' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf (i%2==0)?$i",":""}'
```

or in VIM

```
:%s/,/\r/g
:%s/.*<\(.*\)>/\1/g
```

Comment: `%s/.*<\(.*\)>/\1/g` results in `Fred Flintstone <fred@flintstone.org>
 Wilma Flintstone <wilma@flintstone.org>
 Barney Rubble <barney@rubble.org>
 Bamm-Bamm Rubble <bammbamm@rubble.org>`.

Comment: `:%s/.*<\(.*\)>/\1/g` results in `bammbamm@rubble.org`

Comment: The idea behind Kent's vim code is to split the unique line into several lines, then keep only what's between the angle brackets on each line. Eventually, you'll have to merge all the lines generated into one at the end.

Comment: Thanks Luc Hermitte.  After running both lines, the email address are correctly extracted on separate lines.

Comment: Luc, thanks for the explanation. "J" can be used to join lines.

Answer (score -2):

Could you not put it into Excel,
then split the data on the comma and then 
and then do a find and replace to get rid of the angel bracket

Unless you are using some code to do it this would be the easiest
unless you have 100,000's of thousand addresses