# Vim custom command doesn't work but it works when run manually line by line

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a simple vim command that will get some texts and clean everything else.

The following Vim [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503748/remove-everything-except-regex-match-in-vim) does it:

```
:let @a=""|%s//\=setreg('A', submatch(0), 'l')/g|%d _|pu a|0d _
```

I put this script into a custom command:

```
command! Getlinks :let @a=""|:%s/something/\=setreg('A', submatch(0), 'l')/g|:%d _|:pu a|:0d _
```

When I run `Getlinks` command, it removes everything but doesn't put the matched texts. But when I run the script's commands manually then it works as expected. Why doesn't it put the matched texts when used as `Getlinks` command.

Comment: For me (Vim 7.3.823), both your command and Kent's variant without the superfluous colons do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove those `:`, try this line:

```
command! Getlinks let @a=""|%s/something/\=setreg('A', submatch(0), 'l')/g|%d _|pu a|0d _
```