# Why does setreg not work in Vim's custom command as expected?

Tags: vim

This question is actually related to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639500/vim-custom-command-doesnt-work-but-it-works-when-run-manually-line-by-line) of mine.

I have the following custom command in _vimrc:

```
command! Test %s/some/\=setreg('C', submatch(0), 'l')/g
```

I run this custom command `Test` on the following text:

```
something
```

After running the command the text becomes:

```
=setreg('C', submatch(0), 'l')thing
```

But if I run the same command `%s/some/\=setreg('C', submatch(0), 'l')/g` from the command line of Vim, I get:

```
0thing
```

When running the custom command `Test` the register `C` is not changed. But it is changed when I run the above command from command line which is as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what's bugging you, as with the last time, both of your commands work fine for me.

Usually this is related to some non-default setting, often the `'cpoptions'`. Try with `:set cpo&`, or after `vim -N -u NONE`. Also, check whether the backslash is in the command output of `:command Test`.

Finally (should you not find the root cause), you can work around it by using an intermediate function:

```
function! Test()
    %s/some/\=setreg('C', submatch(0), 'l')/g
endfunction
command! Test call Test()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed adding an additional backslash worked. `command! Test %s/some/\\=setreg('C', submatch(0), 'l')/g` . So, I need to escape backslash in custom commands but not in function definitions.

Comment: Well, normally not (except when you `:execute` the entire `:command` definition and use double quotes). I have no clue why you have to, but as long as it works...