# Remove all words from text not containing a capital letter

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file in vim that looks like this:

```
class ProviderWorker
  def perform opts
    provider  = Provider.find
    MyFitness.perform
    HG.perform
    IWorker.perform
  end
end
```

I want to get rid of all of the text that doesn't contain a word with a capital letter.

I tried:

```
:g/[A-Z]\w+/d
```

However, that doesn't appear to be doing what I expected (nothing was removed).

Expected output:

```
ProviderWorker
Provider
MyFitness
HG
IWorker
```

Comment: Related post: [Remove everything except regex match in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4503748/438329). Note: using `:%!grep -o` is often the easiest way to do this kind of thing. e.g. `:%!grep -o '\<[A-Z]\w\+'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
%s/\v(<\U*>|\W)//
```

where :

- `\v` : use vim's `magic-mode` (see `:h magic`)
- `(<\U*>|\W)`: match either :

  - `<\U*>` : a word (delimited by `<` and `>`) containing only non-uppercase letter (`\U`)
  - `\W` : any non-word character

Comment: Thanks Marth, why is `%s` better here instead of `g` ?  I had to follow this up with `:g/^$/d` in order to get rid of the empty lines this produced

Comment: `:g/re/command` executes `command` on all the lines matching `re`, *linewise*. Here you need to work word-by-word, which `:g` cannot do.